# Increase and reduce index withing a fixed circular range in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a circular range of ascii values of a-z, from 97 to 122.
I am having trouble with decreasing the value, suppose the current value is 100 and i want to reduce it by 4 and it should return 122.

```
const startIndex=97
const endIndex=122

let increaseBy=reduceBy=5
let currentIndex=122
// increment 
// this works
currentIndex=startIndex+((currentIndex-startIndex+increaseBy)%26)

// decrement
// need help
currentIndex=attempted_something_that_you_will_find_it_as_dumb
```

Comment: You can create [a generic indexer](https://jsfiddle.net/bkmsvy45/), which can be used everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo will walk your modulo-class as you wish, if you just keep adding your

`startIndex + (currentIndex%26)`

Now, you just make sure, your currentIndex want go below 0

you modify only the `currentIndex`

```
let startIndex = 97;
let currentIndex = 0;

for(let inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++) {
   currentIndex += 5;
   console.log(startIndex + (currentIndex%26));
}

for(let inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++) {
   currentIndex -= 5;
   console.log(startIndex + (currentIndex%26));
}

console.log("index will go below zero -> will break");
for(let inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++) {
   currentIndex -= 5;
   console.log(startIndex + (currentIndex%26));
}

console.log("index will stop at zero -> will not break");
for(let inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++) {
   currentIndex = Math.max(0, currentIndex - 5);
   console.log(startIndex + (currentIndex%26));
}

console.log("index will reset to modulo at zero -> will not break");
for(let inc = 0; inc < 10; inc++) {
   currentIndex -= 5;
   currentIndex = (currentIndex < 0) ? (26 + currentIndex) : currentIndex;
   console.log(startIndex + (currentIndex%26));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution ***@thst*** gave works well. In short I'll mention my usage of the code

```
const startIndex = 97;
const endIndex = 122;
let currentIndex = 122;
//this value is varies according to the input i take
let increaseBy = (reduceBy = 5);

// increment
currentIndex = startIndex + ((currentIndex - startIndex + increaseBy) % 26);
// decrement
const milansConst=7;
currentIndex = startIndex + ((currentIndex - reduceBy + milansConst) % 26);
```

***milansConst*** is a mysterious number (*there is no logic to it*) my friend came up with to get the decrement expression he made work.

Comment: veryfunny you decrease by 5 and add 7 - you never decrease.